# Inhering node::objectWrap vs class wrapper

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node-modules, embedded-v8

Assume I have a C++ class:

```
class cClass {
public:
    methodA();
    methodB();
private:
    //private stuff
}
```

I can bind this class to Node in two ways:

**Method I - inheriting node::objectWrap directly**

```
class cClass : public node::ObjectWrap {
public:
    static void Init(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports);
    methodA();
    methodB();
private:
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> New(const v8::Arguments& args);
    //private stuff
}
```

In this way I am editing the class structure directly. But there is a simpler way and that is:

**Method II - keeping a reference to original class internally**

```
class cClassWrapper : public node::ObjectWrap {
public:
    static void Init(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports);
private:
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> New(const v8::Arguments& args);
    cClass internal_;
}
```

Notice in **method II** `cClassWrapper` has only one internal field and that is `internal_`. Simply `cClassWrapper` is a user of `cClass` and the internals of `cClass` is untouched.

Obviously Method II is simpler to implement since class structure of `cClass` is untouched but I am wondering what's the downside of it (if any?). Does v8's garbage collector keeps deleting `internal_` when I am passing `cClassWrapper` around?

I am not sure what the differences between the two implementations are.

Answer (score 1):

The seconds option is generally better in terms of architecture: you get a class that is totally decoupled from v8. It can be then moved to some external library, you can track changes (using git or other vcs) of implementation and bindings independently, etc.

The downside is potential performance decrease, which is probably negligible. This doesn't affect garbage collector behaviour at all, all the fields of `ObjectWrap` are managed by `ObjectWrap` implementation.

Comment: what I mean is extra method invocations. but these are really cheap and probably will be inlined anyway.